# How to disconnect from internet using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ras

I have a RAS connection and I need disconnect to it using C#. How I do this? Currently I'm using [dotRas](http://dotras.codeplex.com/) library to handling ras connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this documentation you should just call the [RasHangUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377567%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: This is not a refference to do DotRas SDK buddy

Answer (score 2):

Using the DotRas SDK, you'd just need to get the RasConnection instance you want and call HangUp().

```
using System.Linq;
using DotRas;

RasConnection conn = RasConnection.GetActiveConnections().Where(o => o.EntryName == "My Entry").FirstOrDefault();
if (conn != null)
{
    conn.HangUp();
}
```

Hope that helps!