# block internet using wininet

Tags: c#, wininet

currently i am using wininet in my c# application to check internet connection it is working fine

```
[DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState(out int lpdwFlags, int dwReserved);

    [Flags]
    public enum ConnectionStates
    {
        Modem = 0x1,
        LAN = 0x2,
        Proxy = 0x4,
        RasInstalled = 0x10,
        Offline = 0x20,
        Configured = 0x40,
    }
```

but the problem is i want to block internet but it is not successful how to achieve this using wininet?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to block the internet?  Why?

Comment: @KirkWoll , with all respect , is that really important ? I guess question is something else !!

Comment: @Mehran, it's important because I can think of no conceivable (legitimate) reason that a person would want to write a program that broke their user's internet.

Comment: i am just creating a parental control which can be schedule internet on some specific intervals only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841991/how-to-disconnect-from-internet-using-c

Answer (score 0):

one way is using command prompt in your program :

if you use this command : `rasdial /disconnect` it will disconnect your current internet connection from internet

for executing this command in c# you can use this code :

```
            string command = "rasdial /disconnect";
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
```

another solution from Windows API : [RasHangUp function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa377567%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Internet connection is still there

Comment: execute `rasdial` on cmd , what's the output ?

Comment: and still connected ? so I guess you should go with the API that mentioned above ! I'm not sure but I'm afraid that the API will do the same job as this command does !

Comment: yz still connected,is there any other way with wininet?

Comment: I'll look around , I if find any other solution , I'll let you know ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29931/discussion-between-mad-and-mehran)